# Python OpenCV - VideoCapture.release() won't work in Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv, video-capture

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and Python 2.7.11.

I've written a small program that shows the camera output, and when pressing 'q', closes the camera but doesn't exit the application (for further work...).

The issue is that the webcam is not really released, the LED keeps on and when I try again to open it, it says that the resource is busy, until I completely exit the program.
It DOES work ok in Windows, though...

Here's the code:

```
import cv2
import sys


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        print "BYE"
        break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break       

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
while True:
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to free the camera without exiting the program?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove away the last 2 lines because that is what makes the application hanging (whatever key you press, it stays there)

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ I KNOW!! instead of these lines there's some code relevant to my project...my point is that the application is always on application but must release the camera without exiting

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. I mean your code works perfectly fine on my machine (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, x64 bits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to free the camera (without exiting) is indeed release(). I've tested your code in a Linux Mint 18 (64bit) environment running both OpenCV 2.4.13 and also OpenCV 3.1 with Python 2.7.12. There were no issues.

Here is a way for you to see what is going on in your code:

```
import cv2
import sys

#print "Before cv2.VideoCapture(0)"
#print cap.grab()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

print "After cv2.VideoCapture(0): cap.grab() --> " + str(cap.grab()) + "\n"

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if frame is None:
        print "BYE"
        break

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

print "After breaking, but before cap.release(): cap.grab() --> " + str(cap.grab()) + "\n"

cap.release()

print "After breaking, and after cap.release(): cap.grab() --> " + str(cap.grab()) + "\n"

cap.open(0)
print "After reopening cap with cap.open(0): cap.grab() --> " + str(cap.grab()) + "\n"

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

while True:
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

You may want to think about reinstalling OpenCV on your system. I recommend checking out the awesome guides on PyImageSearch --> http://www.pyimagesearch.com/opencv-tutorials-resources-guides/

*Let me know if this helps!*

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I've done something similar to that before I've written to this site. Try in your code to call cv2.open(0) again after release(). although it should work and re-open the camera, it'll say to you "resource is busy"

Comment: cv2.open(0) will give --> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'open'

Comment: You have to use cap.open(0). After using that it worked. I'll update the answer

Comment: I'll try to re-build opencv

Comment: I will accept you answer even though the problem is not solved, since it's probably has to do with the opencv build

Comment: Now I've noticed that you tested it with OpenCV 3.1, I use 2.4.13 please try with that

Comment: Just tested with OpenCV 2.4.13 as well. Same - works. Will update answer accordingly.

Comment: I wonder...maybe Debian Linux (the one I use..) has different OpenCV implementation ... because exactly the same code doesn't work for me..I get an error when I try to re-open cap

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. By default, my OpenCV build was using Gstreamer as a backend for VideoCapture(). If I forced it to use V4L2 instead, e.g.

```
cap = VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_V4L2)
```

cap.release() worked.

The Gstreamer backend SHOULD be able to close any pipelines it opens (see source code here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp), but for my backend-agnostic application it was easier to avoid than fix that issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anna... I had been stuck with this for a while!