# cannot release VideoCapture for OpenCV

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have this issue with trying to release my Camera from the python program. It keeps telling me that there is invalid syntax

```
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

>>> while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Output -:**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the c of the cap.release
```

This is IDLE Shell 3.9.4 with opencv_contrib_python-4.5.1., and I use Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python OpenCV - VideoCapture.release() won't work in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497384/python-opencv-videocapture-release-wont-work-in-linux)

Comment: nope. it doesnt

Comment: Try to run that code on google colab. If it works, the problem is in your library versions.

Comment: Is this directly within the IDLE Shell? It looks like you copied & pasted this code directly into the Shell environment instead of writing it to a .py & executing it from there.  When you do that you gain an indentation on your while loop and would subsequently get a SyntaxError.  Try again executing from a .py and the error should go away.